# XPath to identify certain groups of children

Tags: xml, xpath

Let's say I have some XML like this:

```
<group>
  <request>
    <field id="a"/>
    <field id="b"/>
    <field id="c"/>
  </request>
  <request>
    <field id="a"/>
    <field id="b"/>
    <field id="d"/>
  </request>
</group>
```

Note that the order of the `<request>` elements is not guaranteed.

I want to come up with two XPath expressions, the first to check that a `<request>` with children a,b and c exists, and the second that a `<request>` with children a,b and d exists.

How do I specify this? The closest I've come uses the numbered predicate syntax, but I'm missing something on how to specify multiple child matches, and the fact that the order of the `<request>` elements is not defined is also tripping me up.

Thanks in advance

Glenn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this what you are looking for ?

```
request[field[@id = 'a'] and field[@id='b'] and field[@id='c']]
```

?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realised that predicates could be nested that way.

Comment: emma, this would select the `request` element (or select nothing). The OP actually wants a boolean to be produced as result of evaluation the XPath expression.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Dimitre, however in this specific case I am using the assertXPathExists() method in [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) so as long as the XPath returns something, it's OK for my purposes.

Comment: @Glenn, My answer is more generic and thus applicable to more use-cases. In particular, it doesn't depend on the availability of assertXpathExists() and on XMLUnit, and can be used in multitude of other situations. So, even if a reader isn't using XMLUnit (which BTW you didn't mention in the question), she would be able to use my answer directly.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to come up with two XPath expressions, the first to check that
>   a `<request>` with children `a`,`b` and `c` exists, and the second
>   that a `<request>` with children `a`,`b` and `d` exists

**Use**:

```
boolean(/*/request[field[@id='a'] and field[@id='b'] and field[@id='c']])
```

**For the second expression use**:

```
boolean(/*/request[field[@id='a'] and field[@id='b'] and field[@id='d']])
```